# Editing answers for removing excuses for answering an old question

Tags: discussion, edits, answers

I often read excuses for answering an old question. Like this one that I quote for the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/866749/2132157):

> I see this question is a bit old, but I decided to give an answer
>   anyway for those who find this question by searching.

I think nobody should beg pardon for answering an old question, so I was tempted to edit the answer for removing the excuses. Is this considered a good practice?

Comment: We mostly prefer that posts solely consist of the questions and answers, so yes I'd remove that as noise. It's worth noting that in traditional discussion forums, "bumping old threads" is often frowned upon, and many such users may be used to that custom and apologize for the potential mistake, when it's not actually a mistake in the SE model.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, I think it is, with some caveats (see below). Basically, it's noise, distracting from the real information in the answer, and it needs to be removed, just like greetings and signatures: [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/295232)

@Sonic is right, many people have an aversion to 'necro-posting' based on their experience with other internet sites, but Stack Exchange even has [two](/help/badges/126/revival) [badges](/help/badges/17/necromancer) to reward this behaviour, so excuses are not needed.

Please keep in mind:

- As with all edits, try to improve other things in the answer as well.
- If the Q&A itself haven't been active for a while, it's not really necessary to bump the question again.
- If you don't have [edit privileges](/help/privileges/edit) and this is the only thing that would warrant an edit, I'd rather not spend a suggested edit on it, to avoid taking reviewers' precious time.